# PayPal REST API - Order and Authorization Amounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Taking the REST API out for a spin, and because my frame of reference is "classic API", specifically `Express Checkout`, I'm pretty much trying to "map" functionality.

Got things going, so this is more "conceptual" than technical..maybe someday this becomes a "wiki"...

Use case: `payment_method:paypal`

1. `payer_info` (Paypal user) is only available after an `execute`

   - in order to successfully (re)calculate totals to account for shipping and tax (based on shipping address), is the proper way of doing this via `order` (not `sale`) thereby allowing an `authorization` and `capture` after such details become available (to merchant)?
   - in other words, we don't have the classic `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` so this seems to be the path(?)
2. Based on this, and testing, can we assume the ["maximum" of 115%](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/) (above `order` total) for the `authorization` call? Based on testing this seems to be true..otherwise `"AUTHORIZATION_AMOUNT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"`

---

**Update**: In case you were wondering:

- you can't [update a payment resource](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#update-a-payment-resource). It's actually stated in the link (but I *had* to try).
- you can't "re-execute" either

<strike>At this point the only thing that works so far is to authorize < 115%</strike>

> The sum of the total open authorizations can’t exceed 115% or $75 (whichever is less) of the amount provided to PayPal when the order was created.

REF: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/

---

3. In docs, [`payer` object](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payer-object) has `status` defined as:

   > Status of the payer’s PayPal account. Currently supported with `paypal payment_method` only, but available for `credit_card payment_method` at a later date. Allowed values: `VERIFIED` or `UNVERIFIED`.

   It doesn't seem to be returned in either `sale` nor `order`.

   <strike>A secondary question therefore becomes, how do you "require" a verified PayPal user (is this now account level setting only - no API override)?</strike>  **See**: [`flow_config`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#flowconfig-object)

The other "missing" items are documented in the API release notes (e.g. `fee`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `order` and `authorize` *intent* can be used to accomplish the flow (adjustments to `authorization` or `capture`) based on PayPal user info.

1. `execute` - returns PayPal `payer_info` - e.g.

   ```
   "payer_info": {
     "email": "foo@noemail.com",
     "first_name": "Ed",
     "last_name": "SF",
     "payer_id": "ABCDEFG",
     "shipping_address": {
       "recipient_name": "Ed SF",
       "line1": "111 Some street",
       "city": "San Francisco",
       "country_code": "US",
       "postal_code": "94111",
       "state": "CA"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Based on the above info, if there are any adjustments needed (i.e. sales tax, shipping),

   - `order` can be `authorized` for the *additional amount** (and subsequently `captured`)
   - `authorization` can be `captured` for the *additional amount**

**additional amount can’t exceed 115% or $75 (whichever is less) of the original `order` or `authorization`, otherwise, `AUTHORIZATION_AMOUNT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` and `CAPTURE_AMOUNT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` errors are raised respectively.*

This is displayed to the user when a `capture` greater than the orginal `authorization` is made:

[image: additional authorization message]

As far as I can tell, there isn't a similar message for an `order` (with adjusted amounts) - the additional authorization amount is displayed in the transaction details (only).